# Android MVI Architecture problem with ui state

Tags: android, architecture, android-livedata

I use  MVI architecture and thought about this scenario that can occur

```kotlin
class MainViewModel() : ViewModel() {

  private val _viewState = MutableLiveData<MainViewState>(MainViewState())
    val viewState: LiveData<MainViewState> get() = _viewState

fun someFun(){
 val newState1=  viewState.value!!.copy(
                   dogName = "dog",
                 )
val newState2=  viewState.value!!.copy(
                  catName = "Cat",
                )
 _viewState.value=newState1
 _viewState.value=newState2

}
data class MainViewState(
var dogName:String="",
var catName:String="",
)
```

The problem is that dogName didn't recieve the update because
I took the same state value before updating it for the first time for DogName
and changed catName with old value of dogName.

Ofc I won't write code like this , but can it occur from different threads or in another way ?

How can I solve it ?
Thanks !